# Weird image filenames

Tags: graphics, external-files

It was a pleasant surprise for me to find out that it is possible to include image named “`K_{2,3}.pdf`” into TeX document using `\includegraphics` (and `pdfLaTeX`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\namedpicture}[1]{\begin{figure}\centering\includegraphics{#1}\caption{$#1$}\end{figure}}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \namedpicture{K_{2,3}}
\end{document}
```

Now I have a question, which doesn't seem to have practical meaning, but is still interesting:) Is it possible to include picture with name containing `%` or imbalanced figure brackets? I. e. I have files `%.pdf`, `{.pdf` and `}.pdf`. How to include any of them?

Comment: If you really have `%.pdf`, I'd say you have a peculiar taste for file name choices. `;-)`

Comment: Imho you are generalizing your success to easily: Your code works on your OS with your current texsystem. I wouldn't accept bets that is works in all OS, for previous versions of a tex system and for other tex-engines.

Comment: I created `%.pdf` just for testing. :) But some name like `Top 3%.pdf` is not too weird.

Comment: I do not generalize anything. I just say that it was possible under my constraints. Anything related to external files is OS-dependent. And even if now something is the same for all existing OSes some time new OS may appear and break the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are expecting only including such files, not automating such a process, the answer is YES. In the following we assume, that angle brackets do not appear in the names of the files and the captions are manually inserted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\newcommand{\namedpicture}[1]{\begin{figure}\centering\includegraphics{#1}\caption{$#1$}\end{figure}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
 %   \namedpicture{K_{2,3}}
\begin{figure}\centering\includegraphics[width=20mm]{K_{2,3}}\caption{$K_{2,3}$}\end{figure}

\catcode`\%=12
\begin{figure}\centering\includegraphics[width=20mm]{%}\caption{\%}\end{figure}
\catcode`\%=14

\catcode`\<=1
\catcode`\>=2
\catcode`\{=12
\catcode`\}=12
\begin<figure>\centering\includegraphics[width=20mm]<{>\caption<\{>\end<figure>

\begin<figure>\centering\includegraphics[width=20mm]<}>\caption<\}>\end<figure>

\catcode`\<=12
\catcode`\>=12
\catcode`\{=1
\catcode`\}=2

\end{document}
```

[image]